# A Free Sample of Autocorrelation

Tags: code-golf, math, statistics

Consider a 1-dimensional, real-valued vector *x* that represents observations of some process measured at equally spaced intervals over time. We call *x* a [**time series**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_series).

Let *n* denote the length of *x* and *x̄* denote the arithmetic mean of *x*. The **sample [autocovariance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocovariance) function** is defined as

[image: autocovariance]

for all -*n* < *h* < *n*. This measures the linear dependence between two points on the same series observed at different times.

The **sample [autocorrelation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocorrelation) function**, or ACF, is defined as

[image: autocorrelation]

This measures the linear predictability of the series *x* at time *t*, which we denote *x*<sub>*t*</sub>, using only the value *x*<sub>*t+h*</sub>.

Note that these sample estimates do not match the naïve calculations based on the theoretical properties. That is, the sample autocorrelation function is *not* equal to the [Pearson correlation coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_product-moment_correlation_coefficient) of *x* with the *h*-step lag of *x*.

### Task

Given an array *x* and a nonnegative integer *h*, print or return the first *h*+1 **lag** autocorrelations of *x*, beginning with lag 0. The lag autocorrelations are those corresponding to negative inputs in the above formulas.

You can assume that 0 < *h* < *n*, where *n* is the length of *x*, and that 2 < *n* < 256.

Output should be correct to within 1E-4. There are no restrictions on the use of built-in functions or running time.

### Examples

```
h, x -> output
--------------
5, [2.4, 2.4, 2.4, 2.2, 2.1, 1.5, 2.3, 2.3, 2.5, 2] -> [1.00000000,  0.07659298, -0.06007802, -0.51144343, -0.02912874, -0.10468140]
1, [2134, 1863, 1877, 1877, 1492, 1249] -> [1.0000000, 0.3343041]
2, [13067.3, 13130.5, 13198.4] -> [1.0000000000, -0.0002854906, -0.4997145094]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Jelly, <s>26</s> <s>25</s> <s>24</s> <s>23</s> 20 bytes

```
×L_SµḊ;0µƓÐ¡×¹S€µF÷Ḣ
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=w5dMX1PCteG4ijswwrXGk8OQwqHDl8K5U-KCrMK1RsO34bii&input=NQ&args=WzIuNCwgMi40LCAyLjQsIDIuMiwgMi4xLCAxLjUsIDIuMywgMi4zLCAyLjUsIDJd)

#### How it works

```
×L_SµḊ;0µƓÐ¡×¹S€µF÷Ḣ  Main link. Input: x (list) STDIN: h (integer)

×L                    Multiply all items in x by the length of x.
  _S                  Subtract the sum of x from all products.
                      Let's call the result X.
    µ                 Begin a new monadic chain. Argument: t (list)
     Ḋ                Remove the first element of t.
      ;0              Append a 0 to the result.
        µ             Push the previous chain and begin a new one.
                      Argument: X
         Ɠ            Read h from STDIN.
          Ð¡          Repeat the Ḋ;0 chain h times, collecting the h+1 intermediate
                      results in a list A.
            ×¹        Multiply the vectors in A by X.
              S€      Compute the sum of each vectorized product.
                µ     Begin a new, monadic chain. Argument: S (sums)
                 F    Flatten S. This does nothing except creating a deep copy.
                   Ḣ  Pop the first element of S.
                  ÷   Divide all elements of the copy by the first element.
```

Answer (score 7):

## R, <s>3</s> <s>31</s> 25 bytes

```
# changes the builtin to only return the acf
body(acf)=body(acf)[1:18]
```

Usage (returns an array with the autocorrelations)

```
(acf(c(2.4, 2.4, 2.4, 2.2, 2.1, 1.5, 2.3, 2.3, 2.5, 2),5))
# , , 1
#
#             [,1]
# [1,]  1.00000000
# [2,]  0.07659298
# [3,] -0.06007802
# [4,] -0.51144343
# [5,] -0.02912874
# [6,] -0.10468140
```

Background:

The 31 byte solution based on the original `acf` built in

```
function(n,h)c(acf(n,h,,F)$acf)
```

Note that the 3 byte option  `acf` is the originalbuilt in that will plot (and print to 3 digits) while returning the required autocorrelation as an element in a list.

usage

```
 acf(c(2.4, 2.4, 2.4, 2.2, 2.1, 1.5, 2.3, 2.3, 2.5, 2),5)
```

output:

```
#    Autocorrelations of series ‘c(2.4, 2.4, 2.4, 2.2, 2.1, 1.5, 2.3, 2.3, 2.5, 2)’, by lag
#
#     0      1      2      3      4      5 
# 1.000  0.077 -0.060 -0.511 -0.029 -0.105
```

If we want the correlations to display to more than 3 decimal places then 28 bytes will do it (or 31, if we want to suppress the plot)

```
# will still plot (28 bytes)
function(n,h)c(acf(n,h)$acf)
# won't plot (31 bytes)
function(n,h)c(acf(n,h,,F)$acf)
```

Comment: This is probably the cleverest trick I have ever seen. I had no idea one could do that. We're trying to get R selected as Language of The Month - you can upvote [this meta answer](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16802/80010) to make it happen.

Answer (score 3):

## Python 3, <s>147</s> <s>130</s> <s>126</s> 120 bytes

```
def p(h,x):x=[t-sum(x)/len(x)for t in x];return[sum(s*t for s,t in zip(x[n:],x))/sum(b*b for b in x)for n in range(h+1)]
```

This solution is probably going to be golfed further, It's just a start.

You can call it with:

```
p(5,[2.4, 2.4, 2.4, 2.2, 2.1, 1.5, 2.3, 2.3, 2.5, 2])
```

Answer (score 2):

## Octave, <s>47</s> 37 bytes

```
@(h,x)xcov(x,'coeff')(numel(x)+(0:h))
```

Comment: @Rainer You can maybe save a few bytes using an anonymous function (and in that case I think you can skip `disp`, because you are returnig a function output)

Comment: @LuisMendo You're right. Saved 10 bytes, even without counting the `disp`.

Comment: Thanks! This is actually really helpful. I've been using Matlab's [`autocorr`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/econ/autocorr.html), but it's part of the Econometrics Toolbox which I don't have access to anymore, so I had to write my own. This is a nice and concise way of calculating it, and in-built `xcorr` is actually really efficient because it uses the fact that autocorrelation and Fourier transform are related ([Wiener-Khinchin theorem](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Wiener-KhinchinTheorem.html)).

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MATL), 20 bytes

```
tYm-tPX+tX>/GnqiQ:+)
```

*EDIT (May 20, 2016): as of version 18.0.0 of the language, use `Y+` instead of `X+`. The link includes this change.*

[**Try it online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=dFltLXRQWSt0WD4vR25xaVE6Kyk&input=WzIuNCwgMi40LCAyLjQsIDIuMiwgMi4xLCAxLjUsIDIuMywgMi4zLCAyLjUsIDJdCjUK)

Correlation is closely related to convolution. We normalize by subtracting mean, then convolve, normalize again by dividing by maximum value, and then pick the desired lags.

```
tYm-       % implicit input. Duplicate and subtract mean
tPX+       % duplicate, flip, convolve
tX>/       % duplicate, divide by maximum value
Gnq        % length of array, n. Subtract 1
iQ:        % input number h. Generate vector [1,2,...,h+1]
+          % add to obtain vector [n,n+1,...,n+h]
)          % use that vector as an index. Implicitly display
```

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 27 bytes

*Thanks to LegionMammal978 for saving 1 byte.*

We could beat Jelly if function names were not so long.

```
#2~CorrelationFunction~{#}&
```

---

**Test case**

```
%[5,{2.4,2.4,2.4,2.2,2.1,1.5,2.3,2.3,2.5,2}]
(* {1.,0.076593,-0.060078,-0.511443,-0.0291287,-0.104681} *)
```

Comment: I was about to post this before my Internet went down... You can save a byte with `#2~CorrelationFunction~{#}&`.